# Automating Adobe Illustrator with NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, scripting, automation, adobe-illustrator

I am developing an NodeJS based application that will automate Adobe Illustrator.
The goal is to use Node to execute a set of Illustrator scripts.
Is this something that is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You can execute arbitrary commands form Node.js with the build in exec library. Documentation is located here: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: I like this answer, but it doesn't give much in terms of actionable options. What binaries can we use or create to interface with Adobe's APIs and how?

Answer (score 0):

For automating the work of Illustrator I suppose, you have to use Illustrator script either in JS, Applescript or VB script. But in case you are making the plugin for CC Application of Illustrator, then you can use node js, npm modules as well. It depends on how and where you want to use. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

It is something that is possible but not in the standard "node" sense.
In example.  Create file => run file.
To execute a node file you would write up some code:

```
const myFunc = (options) => {
console.log(options)
}
```

in node you can just run it and it would work.
With Adobe Illustrator scripting it's more like this:

```
Create file => evalScript => illustrator runs evaluated script and executes code in illustrator.
```

From the answers given here and in many other places one would think you can run any node packages in Illustrator and Illustrator would just work.  Actually the JS version illustrator is running isn't the latest one so there are several things you can't do IN illustrator CEP.

You can do a lot of stuff, just have to find work arounds.
More info here:
https://github.com/Adobe-CEP

CEP extension samples here:
https://github.com/ten-A/CEP_Extension_Samples/tree/master/minimalSample